# same operation in multiple if statement, how to reduce code redundancy

Tags: c++, redundancy

The delete statement below is a code redundancy.

```
int *a = new int[100]
if (!doSomething1(a))
   delete[] a
   return
if (!doSomething2(a))
   delete[] a
   return
if (!doSomething3(a))
   delete[] a
   return

return
```

One alternative I came up with is:

```
if(doSomething1(a) || doSomething2(a) || doSomething3(a))
   ;
delete[] a;
return;
```

But it does not fit in situation where I want to add instructions specified to doSomething1(), e.g.

```
if(!doSomething1(a))
   foo;
   delete[] a;
   return;
if(!doSomething2(a))
   delete[] a;
   return;
```

I was told there are at least 5 ways to reduced this kind of code redundancy. So any suggestions?

---

update, one more question:
same question, Let's limit the domain to C only, note process logic change.

```
char *a = (char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
if(doSomething1(a))
   foo;
   free(a)
   return;
if(doSomething2(a))
   free(a)
   return;
if(doSomething3(a))
   free(a);
   return;
free(a);
return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need to manually delete anything? This is C++, so we can use destructors and [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization).

```
std::vector<a>(100);
if (!doSomething1(a))
    return;
if (!doSomething2(a))
    return;
if (!doSomething3(a))
    return;
```

More generally: if anything needs to happen when you leave a scope, then do it in the destructor of an automatic object in that scope.

But why are you using return values to indicate failure? This is C++, so we can use exceptions:

```
std::vector<a>(100);
doSomething1(a);
doSomething2(a);
doSomething3(a);
```

Comment: Your points are valid, but I think his/her question was about control structures, not memory allocation.  I think the memory allocation was just a generic stand-in for whatever code.

Comment: Yesss!!! Exceptions, so *nobody* will see the twisted control flow behind the code. Dijkstra and your "goto considered harmful", we can do much, much worse! Take that!! **(Evil laughter echoing)**

Comment: @IronSavior: The answer is the same in the general case: if something has to be done when leaving the current scope, do it in the destructor of a scoped automatic object.

Comment: @vonbrand: Or, to put it another way: exceptions, so *nobody* can ignore an error condition and carry on into undefined behaviour. After three or so decades of mainstream use, most people don't regard their flow as "twisted".

Comment: @MikeSeymour You are correct and I agree this is the most appropriate answer.  Your first sentence was a comment about memory management and since the asker may not actually have a memory management problem, he/she may discount your answer without seeing the wisdom in RAII.

Comment: @MikeSeymour What does 'twisted control flow' mean, exception chain?

Comment: @MikeSeymour I have updated one more question, do you mind to take a look?

Comment: @Sky: I'm a C++ programmer, and this is a C++ question. If you have a question about a different language, ask a separate question with the appropriate language tag.

Answer (score 1):

"RAII" and "scope exit" would be good search terms for Google or SO. For example, look at [Boost.ScopeExit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/scope_exit/doc/html/index.html) or the [alternatives to it](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/scope_exit/doc/html/scope_exit/alternatives.html). The idea is that you create a local object and leave it to the **destructor** to do the cleanup or "finally" code.

Here's an attempt at applying the idiom directly to your example, reduced to the bare minimum (no error checking and stuff like that):

```
class AutomaticDeleter
{
public:
    AutomaticDeleter(int *a) : a(a) {}
    ~AutomaticDeleter() { delete[] a; }
    int *GetWrappedPointer() const { return a; }
private:
    int *a;
};

// ...

AutomaticDeleter automatic_deleter(new int[100]);

if (!doSomething1(automatic_deleter.GetWrappedPointer()))
   return;
if (!doSomething2(automatic_deleter.GetWrappedPointer()))
   return;
if (!doSomething3(automatic_deleter.GetWrappedPointer()))
   return;
```

And of course, I should mention that this is just an example of what you *can* do, not of what you *should* do when applying the idiom to a pointer, especially one returned from `new[]`. In real life, you'd use `std::vector<int>` and be done with it. The idiom has much more interesting and useful applications.

Comment: This is a nice explanation, I couldn't fully appreciate MikeSeymou's answer without it. However, since MikeSeymour covers more information(but not that plain to the person asking this kind of question), I'll chose MikeSeymours as accepted answer.

Comment: @Sky: not a problem at all. I've been digitally socialised in Usenet, where reputation was not expressed as a number displayed next to a nickname. I must admit I like the SO system, but I know one should not get carried away with it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
do {
    if (doSomething1(a) && doSomething2(a) && doSomething3(a)){
        break; /*all good: move outside the dummy loop*/
    }
    /*one of the functions failed*/
    delete[] a;
    return;
} while (false);
```

is one way. I'm relying on the fact that `if` evaluates statements strictly from left to right and will stop evaluation once a `false` is reached.

(This idiom is used quite frequently in C; see unix kernel source code).

Comment: Personally, I'd rather see a real `goto` than a weirdly disguised one; and I'd rather see C++ idioms than those from a different language.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: A `goto` requires your using a label for starters; the `do` `while` is cleaner in that respect.

Comment: It's not that `if` evaluates statements strictly from left to right. This is a non-sense. It's that logic operators are short-circuited.

Comment: @bolov: added, in simple terminology.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool failure;

int *a = new int[100]
if ( failure = !doSomething1(a))
   //...
if ( !failure && ( failure = !doSomething2(a) ) )
   //...
if ( !failure && ( failure =!doSomething3(a) ) )
   //...

if ( failure )
{
   delete []a;
   return;
}
//,,,   

return
```